# How to change default Terminal in Source Tree on windows

Tags: windows, cmd, terminal, console, atlassian-sourcetree

I am working on Windows 7 with Source Tree. Because I don't like the default cmd.exe I want to change it to Console2 such that Source Tree will open Command2 instead of Cmd as terminal.

Comment: I don't think this is an option. You may want to consider just changing the default terminal: http://superuser.com/questions/509642/how-to-change-the-default-terminal-emulator-on-windows-cmd

Comment: This feature is missing, and Atlassian are going to add it -- https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-173

Answer (score 4):

It appears you can't do it, at least in any obvious way.  There are a couple of solutions/workarounds that you can use here:

1. Pick a different favorite terminal.  [ConEmu](http://conemu.github.io/) is a wrapper for `CMD.exe` that will act as your default terminal if you tell it to [*I thought `Console2` could do this as well*].  Also - *forgive the editorial* - ConEmu is way, way, better than `Console2`.
2. You can add a custom action in the menu.  From the global options go to `Custom Actions` tab and add an action to `Open in Terminal` using the console you want.  This isn't quite as cool as just hitting the terminal icon, but you can easily accomplish the same outcome.

Unfortunately, these are the best there are for now.

*Note*:  Based upon the link that [@sendmoreinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1097572/sendmoreinfo) posted, waiting for Atlassian to add this by default may be better way to go for your purposes.  Only problem with that may be is that according to some the newest updates to Source tree [are terrible](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/36184030/latest-sourcetree-update-is-terrible), so I haven't updated as of yet.

*Note 2*: Though this won't do what you want, there is an Option in the settings under the `Git Tab` that allows you to `Set Git Bash as default prompt`.  That may or may not get you closer to where you want to be.

Answer (score 2):

You may add **Windows Terminal** as **Custom Action**. You may run custom action in context of selected file. Define a new custom action as shown below.

[image]